# Display inserted image from previous page

Tags: php, image

I'm making a classified website that allows users to insert an image. The image data is sent thorugh the form to the page verify.php. Is it possible to display the image on verify.php? I've tried looking online but I only found answers from people inserting the image to mysql first and then displaying it.

Here is my code for the page where I want the image to be displayed.

```
$name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$type = $_FILES["image"]['type'];
$size = $_FILES["image"]["size"];
$temp = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$error = $_FILES['image']["error"];
echo "<img src='$temp'>"; //this displays the 
                          //binary code(I beleive that's what it s called)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value in `$temp` is the binary form of the image! So you can either `base64_encode()` it and display it this way:

```
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($temp) . "'>";
```

Comment: what if image is not PNG?

Comment: Also he needs to encode the binary to base64 like: echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($temp)."'>"

Comment: This does not work. I get a broken link image and the binary code is displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NaeemAhmed Can you try: `echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($temp) . "'>";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php) method and store image somewhere in public directory of server:

```
$name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
echo "<img src=\"$uploads_dir/$name\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possibilities:

Method 1:
Tell your browser that veryfy.php is an image. This works with

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

or any other image type (depending on your result).
However this method does not allow you to publish text at same time.

Method 2:
Save you picture (in database or on a fileserver) and then load it with <img...>

Method 3:
Use base64 encoding:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA...">
```

However, this one should only be used for small files since it will slow down loading of page. More information: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)